# Can't equip a new jetpack

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I was playing Jetpack Joyride and I just bought a jetpack (Red Barry), the Paper Bag Head and Barrel. I went to equip it but I've only equiped my Barrel.
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Go to shop and find *Jetpack*, tap on a jetpack and press *Equip*.
In the next game jetpack will be on your character.